# Is it possible to find the partial sum?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Let, $a_n=\frac {3^{n+1}}{1+2^{n+1}},n\geq0.$ Let $S_n$ be the partial sum defined by 
$$S_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i.$$
Is it possible to write a closed formula for $S_n.$ I have no idea how to do this. Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need a closed formula? For large $n$, $a_n$ behaves like $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n+1}$, and $\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{i+1}$ is just $\frac{3^{n+2}}{2^{n+1}}-3$.

Comment: Thanks Jack, But I need the closed  for some other reason..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have:
$$ S_N = \sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{3^{n+1}}{1+2^{n+1}} = \sum_{n=0}^{N}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n+1}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}=\sum_{n=0}^{N}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n+1}\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^m}{2^{(n+1)m}}$$
hence by exchanging the sum on $m$ and the sum on $n$,
$$ S_N = 3\sum_{m\geq 0}(-1)^{m}\frac{2^{(m+1)(N+1)}-3^{N+1}}{(2^{m+1}-3)2^{(m+1)(N+1)}}$$
the last series converges pretty fast for any $N$, but I won't bet on a simple closed form but in terms of the Hurwitz zeta function or something related.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer...